# Rails : Send email with Mailjet Api V3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, mailjet

I try to send an email with the new mailjet api (v3).
Here is my config :

**gemfile**

> > gem 'mailjet'

**config/initializers/mailjet.rb**

```
Mailjet.configure do |config|
  config.api_key = '<my api>'
  config.secret_key = '<my_psw>'
  config.default_from = 'mail@conicrea.com'
  config.domain = 'localhost'
end
```

**mailer.rb**

```
  def send_unsubscribe(user)
    @user = user
    @to = "paul@conicrea.com"
    @from = "mail@conicrea.com"

    mail(to: @to, from: @from, subject: "TTP Tork - Demande de désinscription") do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end
```

**user.rb**

```
def send_unsubscribe
  Mailer.send_unsubscribe(self).deliver
end
```

> > u.send_unsubscribe

In log, the mail seems to be create en send but there is no email in my mailbox and in mailjet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're looking to use Mailjet's SMTP relay.  Here is how to configure it this way:

Start off by changing this line `config.domain = 'localhost'` to your registered domain name rather than just 'localhost'.

Next, add this `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :mailjet_smtp` to your application.rb file

Not entirely sure which hosting service you are using, but check out [this link](https://www.mailjet.com/support/how-to-setup-domainkeys-dkim-and-spf-in-my-dns-records,84.htm).  It shows you how to configure your SPF and DKIM settings for each hosting service to accommodate Mailjet.